# How to simplify Tensorboard graph with shared variables?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm working with `cifar10` model of Tensorflow. I use the `inference` function for both training and evaluation pipelines and share all the variables inside. My Tensorboard graph visualization looks like in the pic.

Arrows between two main columns (e.g. `conv1 -> conv1_1`) inside the `inference` scope hopefully reflect that all the `conv1` variables are shared.

At the same time, node `conv1_1` doesn't exist in the code. It looks like it's replicated from `conv1` to separate the pipeline for my two inputs.

My question is what all of `*_1` nodes in the graph exactly mean? Do scopes and functions in Tensorflow get replicated when I use them with different inputs? 
The main question: is there a way to hide `*_1` nodes in the graph visualization because they are confusing and messy.

[image: tensorboard graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue (still open) on GitHub with a workaround https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9545

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import variable_scope as var_scope

def simple_variable_scope(name_or_scope, reuse=None):
  """Creates a variable scope without also creating a name scope."""
  return var_scope.variable_scope(name_or_scope, reuse=reuse,
                                  auxiliary_name_scope=False)
```

Comment: Yep, that bug describes exactly the same behavior